# How do you extract rows given conditions on two columns using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, extract

```
os.chdir("C:\Users\EDAWES01\Desktop\Cookie profiling")
data = pandas.read_csv('activity_url.csv', delimiter=';')
data_read=np.array(data)
quantity = data_read[0:, 2]
other_data = data_read[0:, 1]
x="http"
url_data = data_read[np.logical_and(quantity==1, any(x in other_data)][:,1] #extraction
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for selecting and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""0;1;2
0;http;1
5;http1;0
8;aa2;7
9;fffhttp;1"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp) to filename
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), sep=";")
print (data)
   0        1  2
0  0     http  1
1  5    http1  0
2  8      aa2  7
3  9  fffhttp  1

x="http"
url_data = data[(data.iloc[:, 2] == 1) & (data.iloc[:, 1].str.contains(x))]
print (url_data)
   0        1  2
0  0     http  1
3  9  fffhttp  1

print (url_data.iloc[:,1])
0       http
3    fffhttp
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for upvoting - now you can upvote each answer in StackOverflow, what is helful for you. ;) Nice day!